# JQuery Colorbox: Disabled links outside of the viewport?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I found an interesting issue while working with colorbox lightbox. (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)
I want to use the lightbox without having the black background, so I'm hiding it with css. And now comes the strange behaviour:
 - On the first viewport beside the colorbox the links are just working fine.
 - If you scroll down, the links are not working anymore, and the window jumps to the top.
You can see it in action under http://testsite.mediasharks.net/en/Contact

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i fugred out, that the 'tabindex' property causes this issue, also the fix for this is:

```
 onComplete: function () {
     $("#cboxOverlay").remove();
     $('#colorbox').removeAttr('tabindex');
}
```